# Parameter value not coming through on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, servlets

On the top of my server's doPost I collect the parameter names arriving and iterate through them to collect their values using request.getParameterValues(pName).  That has been well tested and is currently producing this for my new transaction:

```
                NodeID : []

              function : [modify]
```

This tells me that the parameter 'NodeID' is being sent, but no value is coming through.  I put in an alert just before form submission to see what the form looked like in the developer's DOM display, and it appears as so:

```
<form id="modify" action="/BackToTech/server?function=modify" method="post">
  <input name="NodeID" value="28" />
</form>
```

This is the javascript function producing and submitting the form.

```
  function modify(nodeID) {
    alert("node.id = " + nodeID);
    var root = document.body;
    var form = $('<FORM>')
                    .attr('action', "/BackToTech/server?function=modify")
                    .attr('method', "post")
                    .attr('id', "modify")
                    .appendTo(root);
                $('<INPUT>')
                    .attr('name', 'NodeID')
                    .attr('value', nodeID)
                    .appendTo(form);
                //alert('delay');
    $('#modify').submit();
  }
```

The first alert reports nodeID is 28.

Any errors jump out at you?  I thought I did the same thing recently for a delete transaction and got it working before replacing it with an ajax call instead, so I have confidence in the approach.  I guess I might as well include the top of my server's doPost:

```
    Enumeration<String> pNames = request.getParameterNames();
    ArrayList<String> parameterNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(pNames.hasMoreElements()) 
        parameterNames.add(pNames.nextElement());
    Object[] orderedNames = parameterNames.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(orderedNames); //.sort(parameterNames)

    for(int i=0; i<orderedNames.length; i++) {
        String pName = orderedNames[i].toString();
        for(int v=0; v<(25-pName.length()); v++) {
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        System.out.println(pName + " : " + Arrays.asList(request.getParameterValues(pName)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  Had a form I'd forgotten about in the navigation pane with the same name.  Submission was being done on that path to this transaction, where no one had selected a NodeID from an accompanying select box.